# Split 2 word cell and insert into new rows using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm uber new to Python. I have searched through the database and did not find an exact answer to my question. Here is my basic problem:

I have a CSV file of the form:

```
Header1,        Header2,             Header3   
1,                a,                DF FD CN 
2,                 b,               DD FD CN
```

that I need to write out as a csv in the following form: Instead of first space in the Header 3 column, I would like to split on the second space in the Header 3 column.

```
Header1,     Header2,     Header3  
1,             a,         DF  FD
1,             a,         FD  CN
2,             b,         DD  FD
2,             b,         FD  CN
```

Right now I am here with my code:

```
import csv  
import sys
import codecs
import re

splitColIndex = 0

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
   with open('input.txt') as f:  
       reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ':')   
       for row in reader:

           # Get the element that needs splitting
           splitElem = (row[splitColIndex])
           A=splitElem.split()
           for f in sorted(set(A)):
            print(f+':'+row[1]+'\n')
f2.close()
```

My question now is how do I split the space-separated values in column three at the second space and get to the output I am trying to achieve? My actual file is more complicated, but I think an answer to this will get me in the right direction.

Comment: Shouldn't `splitColIndex` be 2?  Shouldn't you be writing to `f2`?  Shouldn't you *not* be re-using `f`?

Comment: Yes. splitColIndex should be 2 and writing to f2. I am not sure what do you mean by Shouldn't you not be re-using f? –

Comment: You re-define `f` in the inner-loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv  
import sys
import codecs
import re

# Index (starts at 0) of the column that needs to be split up
splitColIndex = 2

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
   with open('input.txt') as f:  
       reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ':')   
       for row in reader:

           # Get the element that needs splitting
           splitElem = (row[splitColIndex])
           words=splitElem.split()
           k=[words[index]+' '+words[index+1] for index in xrange(len(words)-1)]
           for f1 in k:
               print(f1)
            f2.write(f1+':'+row[1]+'\n')
f2.close()
```